# In Python how do I create variable length combinations or permutations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, list-comprehension

Lets say I have an array called arr = [1,2,3,4]

How can I generate all the possible combinations with minimum 2 arguments that end up looking like

```
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,4]
[1,2,3]
[1,2,4]
[1,2,3, 4]
[2,3]
[2,4]
```

and so on and so forth?  Nothing Im trying works.  I cant seem to use itertools.combinations or permutations because I need to know the argument size and I cant seem to use itertools.products because that will take minimum one argument from each of a list of lists that looks like this `[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]`.  Extra thanks for one liners and comprehensions.

If I wanted to add them all together would that be too much to ask in terms of help? ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about:

```
(x for l in range(2, len(arr)) for x in itertools.combinations(arr, l))
```

or

```
[x for l in range(2, len(arr)) for x in itertools.combinations(arr, l)]
```

if you need the list.

This is the equivalent of the following nested loop

```
res = []
for l in range(2, len(arr)):
    for x in itertools.combinations(arr, l):
        res.append(x)
return res
```

Comment: +1 for list comprehension.  Do you mind telling me how this works though? This isnt a nested loop right?

Answer (score 1):

From : http://wiki.python.org/moin/Powerful%20Python%20One-Liners use following to create all subsets and then refine those with length less than 2

```
f = lambda x: [[y for j, y in enumerate(set(x)) if (i >> j) & 1] for i in range(2**len(set(x)))]

print [k for k in f([1,2,3,4]) if len(k) >1]
```